# How to install Tomcat 8 on Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty LTS using the "apt-get" way?

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat8

I've already installed java8 on this server, then I want to install tomcat8 using the "apt-get" way(not the binary way).But After lots of googling,I can't find the solution，most of the solutions are using the binary way(download the apache-tomcat-8.X.X.tar.gz,then unzip it and start the tomcat...)

Comment: Shoun't that be asked here? http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue that you are running into is that no one has yet created a Debian package for the installation of Tomcat 8.  Until this happens you will need to do it manually (the "unzip" method) after installing the JDK via apt.

Comment: I agree with you.It seems that there's only tomcat8 Debian package for Ubuntu 14.10.